# Indirect parameter substitution in shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, posix

I'm having a problem with a shell script (POSIX shell under HP-UX, FWIW).  I have a function called print_arg into which I'm passing the name of a parameter as $1.  Given the name of the parameter, I then want to print the name and the value of that parameter.  However, I keep getting an error.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

function print_arg
  {
  # $1 holds the name of the argument to be shown

  arg=$1

  # The following line errors off with
  #   ./test_print.sh[9]: argval=${"$arg"}: The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

  argval=${"$arg"}

  if [[ $argval != '' ]] ; then
    printf "ftp_func: $arg='$argval'\n"
  fi
  }

COMMAND="XYZ"

print_arg "COMMAND"
```

I've tried re-writing the offending line every way I can think of.  I've consulted the local oracles.  I've checked the online "BASH Scripting Guide".  And I sharpened up the ol' wavy-bladed knife and scrubbed the altar until it gleamed, but then I discovered that our local supply of virgins has been cut down to, like, nothin'.  Drat!

Any advice regarding how to get the value of a parameter whose name is passed into a function as a parameter will be received appreciatively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `eval`, though using direct indirection as [suggested by SiegeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380478/indirect-parameter-substitution-in-shell-script/4380496#4380496) is probably nicer if you can use `bash`.

```
#!/bin/sh

foo=bar
print_arg () {
    arg=$1
    eval argval=\"\$$arg\"
    echo "$argval"
}
print_arg foo
```

Comment: thanks much.  I also thought @SiegeX's answer was a nice solution (and many thanks to @SiegeX for offering it up), but unfortunately the ${!foo} construct errored off under the POSIX shell in the same way that my attempts had.  Yours worked perfectly under POSIX.  Many thanks.

Comment: @Bob: There's no need for the command substitution, and in fact it would cause harm (depending on the shell, backslashes in the string and an initial `-` may be interpreted by `echo`, and trailing newlines would be stipped by the command substitution). Even simpler, you could just write `eval argval="\$$1"`.

Comment: @Gilles: thanks for the additional feedback.  I've taken your simpler code and am running with it.  :-)

Comment: Unless you're sure what can be passed to the function, it makes sense to remove from the argument any unnecessary characters: `arg=$(echo "$arg" | tr -d $'\n' | sed -r 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]//g'); eval argval=\$$arg`.

Comment: Or even: `arg=$(echo "$arg" | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9_'); eval argval=\$$arg`.

Answer (score 8):

In bash (but not in other sh implementations), indirection is done by: `${!arg}`

#### Input

```
foo=bar
bar=baz

echo $foo
echo ${!foo}
```

#### Output

```
bar
baz
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, under the POSIX shell we're stuck with here this construct didn't work.  I tagged this question with 'bash' because *most of the time* BASH shell stuff works fine under the POSIX shell.  Sadly, not this time.  But many thanks anyways.

Comment: @Bob: There are *many* things that Bash can do that are not possible in a POSIX-only shell. It's better to be clear about your constraints than to imply something that you can't use.

Answer (score 1):

This worked surprisingly well:

```
#!/bin/sh
foo=bar

print_arg () {
    local line name value
    set | \
    while read line; do
        name=${line%=*} value=${line#*=\'}
        if [ "$name" = "$1" ]; then
            echo ${value%\'}
        fi
    done
}

print_arg foo
```

It has all the POSIX clunkiness, in Bash would be much sorter, but then again, you won't need it because you have `${!}`. This -*in case it proves solid*- would have the advantage of using only builtins and **no `eval`**. If I were to construct this function using an external command, it would have to be `sed`. Would obviate the need for the read loop and the substitutions. Mind that asking for indirections in POSIX without eval, has to be paid with clunkiness! So don't beat me!

Comment: Are you sure that in POSIX every value is enclosed in `'`? Then, what if `foo=some\'value`?

Comment: @x-yuri hmmm you're right, perhaps it's best to just look at the first = character in the line and separate lhs and rhs right there. I'll revise that and edit if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the answer's already accepted, here's another method for those who need to preserve newlines and special characters like Escape ( `\033` ): Storing the variable in **base64**.

You need: **bc, wc, echo, tail, tr, uuencode, uudecode**

### Example

```
#!/bin/sh


#====== Definition =======#
varA="a
b
c"
# uuencode the variable
varB="`echo "$varA" | uuencode -m -`"
# Skip the first line of the uuencode output.
varB="`NUM=\`(echo "$varB"|wc -l|tr -d "\n"; echo -1)|bc \`; echo "$varB" | tail -n $NUM)`"


#====== Access =======#

namevar1=varB
namevar2=varA

echo simple eval:
eval "echo \$$namevar2"
echo simple echo: 
echo $varB
echo precise echo: 
echo "$varB"
echo echo of base64
eval "echo \$$namevar1"
echo echo of base64 - with updated newlines
eval "echo \$$namevar1 | tr ' ' '\n'"
echo echo of un-based, using sh instead of eval (but could be made with eval, too)
export $namevar1
sh -c "(echo 'begin-base64 644 -'; echo \$$namevar1 | tr ' ' '\n' )|uudecode"
```

### Result

```
simple eval:
a b c
simple echo:
YQpiCmMK ====
precise echo:
YQpiCmMK
====
echo of base64
YQpiCmMK ====
echo of base64 - with updated newlines
YQpiCmMK
====
echo of un-based, using sh instead of eval (but could be made with eval, too)
a
b
c
```

### Alternative

You also could use the `set` command and parse it's output; with that, you don't need to treat the variable in a special way before it's accessed.

Comment: Why would you store a value in base64? `sh` can store values with `\033` and other characters. And they're preserved by `eval val=\$$name`.

Comment: There are rare cases where this is needed. All of following must be true: 1. no performance requirements, 2. working with command substitution (``) because normal substitution e.g. in POSIX shell is not sufficient, 3. last newlines matter

Comment: And 4. you don't want to use functions. [use case: concatenation]

Comment: I must admit I cannot remember when I used base64 encoded variables last time

Comment: And I must admit I didn't know that you can assign variables without quoting (`a=$b`).

Comment: [Quoting when assigning is incidental anyway]

Comment: There're ways to preserve newlines, e.g.: `a=$'\n'; b=\`echo "$a"x\`; b=${b%x}`. And to confirm: `echo -n "$b" | od -c`. This I understand resolves concerns #2 and #3. (Or else I don't understand what means "not sufficient.") Regarding me carelessly mentioning `eval val=\$$name`. That's okay if you're sure that `$name` doesn't contain anything funny (a legitimate variable name, not `$; rm some-file` or something). If not, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36235741/52499).

Answer (score 1):

A safer solution with `eval`:

```
v=1

valid_var_name='[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*$'

print_arg() {
    local arg=$1
    if ! expr "$arg" : "$valid_var_name" >/dev/null; then
        echo "$0: invalid variable name ($arg)" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    local argval
    eval argval=\$$arg
    echo "$argval"
}

print_arg v
print_arg 'v; echo test'
```

Inspired by the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36235741/52499).