# in POSIX shell, how to print the value of the value of a variable

Tags: shell, posix

In a POSIX shell:

```
>VALUE=value
>FOOBAR=VALUE
```

Now how to print the value of `$FOOBAR`? `$$FOOBAR` does not work - it goes left-to-right so interprets `$$` first as process ID.

The duplicate question before me that people are pointing to, yes it does contain the answer to my question but it buried in a ton of irrelevant gunk.  My question is much simpler and to the point.

Comment: Did you try `$($FOOBAR))`?

Comment: @Bharel of course does not work, for the same reason as above - the shell interprets left to right

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757380/bash-variable-variables

Comment: @KarolyHorvath yes there is the answer there in your link, use `eval`:  `eval echo \$$FOOBAR`  .  Please make it an answer, I will accept.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indirect parameter substitution in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380478/indirect-parameter-substitution-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this in POSIX is to use `eval`, so be **very** certain that `FOOBAR` contains nothing more than a valid variable name.

```
$ VALUE=value
$ FOOBAR=VALUE
$ valid_var='[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*$'
$ expr "$FOOBAR" : "$valid_var" > /dev/null && eval "echo \$$FOOBAR"
```

Comment: It's best to assign the value with `eval` to some variable before printing: `eval val=\$$FOOBAR; echo "$val"`. In your case the argument is not quoted. Also, I was thinking about `FOOBAR=$(echo "$FOOBAR" | tr -dc [:alnum:]_); eval val=\$$FOOBAR`. Or `[ "$FOOBAR" != "$(echo "$FOOBAR" | tr -dc [:alnum:]_)" ] && eval ...` (or terminate the script right away). But your solution is a bit better (always start with alpha).

Answer (score 1):

For POSIX portability, you are pretty much left with

```
eval echo \$$variable
```

The usual caveats apply; don't use `eval` if the string you pass in is not completely and exclusively under your own control.

I lowercased your example; you should not be using upper case for your private variables, as uppercase names are reserved for system use.